# Primitive = Non-negative + Irreducible + 1 Positive element on main diagonal

Tags: matrices, proof-writing

Can anyone provide me with the proof for the sufficient condition for a matrix to be primitive as described by the definition from planetmath.org? (http://planetmath.org/primitivematrix)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the condition that $P_{ii}>0,$ for some $i$ creates the *aperiodicity* of the matrix. The period of the state $i$ is defined as:
$$ d(i)= \gcd\{ n: P^n_{ii} >0\}=1.$$
Since, the matrix is irreducible, all the states have the same period, namely $d = 1$ (i.e. the matrix is aperiodic). Thus, we have an irreducible and aperiodic matrix. Now, this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172313/why-is-every-irreducible-matrix-with-period-1-primitive) addresses the question why an irreducible and aperiodic matrix is primitive.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315453/how-does-one-show-a-matrix-is-irreducible-and-reducible